# How to set value for foreign key

Tags: java, hibernate, setter

I can't set `deptID` value which is a foreign key I tried many ways, but it doesn't work.

I am getting the values from HTML form.

mapping table units

```html
public BigDecimal getUnitId() {
    return this.unitId;
}

public void setUnitId(BigDecimal unitId) {
    this.unitId = unitId;
}

public Depts getDepts() { //deptID column - FK
    return this.depts;
}

public void setDepts(Depts depts) {
    this.depts = depts;
}
```

my code

```html
<%
    SessionFactory sf=  new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
    Session s= sf.openSession();
    Transaction t= s.beginTransaction();
    String unitID= request.getParameter("unitID");
    String deptID= request.getParameter("deptID");
    String unitName= request.getParameter("unitName");
    Units r= new Units(); //this code to set deptID
    Depts y= new Depts();
    r.setUnitId(new BigDecimal(unitID));
    //r.setDepts(y.setDeptId(new BigDecimal(deptID)));//here is my problem
    y.setDeptId(new BigDecimal(deptID));
    r.setUnitName(unitName);
    s.save(r);
    t.commit();
    out.println("done enserting");
%>
```

Comment: show how did you try to set that value and possible exceptions

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38147196/hibernate-one-to-many-getters-setters-issues

Comment: Question get  updated

Answer (score 0):

I could suspect the error by looking at  your code that you're trying to save the `value` which you're receiving from your html page, **instead** of saving the `object` of your `Department` (or your class name which has deptID primary-key) class.

In order to save the deptID along with your record :- 
you need to get the object of that class first. Something like  this :-

```
Units r = new Units(); 

YourDepartmentClass d = getDeparmentRecord(id) //get the  `YourDepartmentClass` class object on the basis of the id you're receiving 

r.setDepId(d);  //set/associate YourDepartmentClass object in your Unit's object

//save the record
```